# Synchronization blocks

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm a newbie to threads and specifically the `synchronized` key word.

I understand that a thread's state changes to `BLOCKED` if it tried to access a synchronized block where another thread already owns the lock.

For reference:

```
synchronized (objA){
    objA.methodA();
}

//some code

objA.methodB();
```

My question is whether another thread can alter the object `objA` through another independent method (`methodB()` in this example). Or does owning the lock mean that no other thread can access/alter `objA` in any way ie whether or not the alteration code is within the synchronized block?

Comment: is it then possible that a method which is not synchronized is called on `objA` while another thread owns the monitor?

Comment: Yes. Any thread can call a non-synchronized method at any time, since it doesn't need to hold any lock to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronizing on a object locks the monitor of the object.
It means that no synchronized method or synchronized statement on an object can be executed if a thread is already executing in a synchronized statement (or a synchronized method) on this same object.

But things are different for no synchronized methods.
Indeed, any thread may invoke any no synchronized method on `objA` while a thread is executing in a synchronized statement on this same `objA`.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only thing that owning the monitor (lock) means, is that no other thread can also own it until you give it up.

Of course, that does mean that they can't call any `synchronized` methods on objA (since that requires acquiring the lock), so if all of the modification methods on objA are synchronized (or use `synchronized (this) {...}` blocks), then the "no" becomes a "yes."

But if `methodB` never tries to lock on `this` (either by being synchronized, or by using a synchronized block), then no amount of locking on `objA` will block calls to `objA.methodB()`.

Comment: Note that a properly synchronized object also needs to synchronize the methods **reading** the state that is guarded by synchronized blocks. Only synchronizing the "modification methods" is not sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet Good point! The exception is if that state is in `volatile` fields -- but that's a more advanced topic.